# Non jQuery lightbox

Tags: javascript

I have a Mindtouch powered website that seems to hate jQuery. If I load it up it comes in conflict site some CMS native JavaScript and makes my site navigation stop functioning.

I have been looking for days for a nice lightbox written in JavaScript not jQuery that will automatically lightbox all links to images that have an image as content.

```
<a href='someimage.jpeg,jpg,png,gif'><img src='thumb.jpeg,jpg,png,gif'/></a>
```

If anyone can point out at least one plese.
Google was not good help for me as all results are jQuery based except some ancient ones that just look terrible.

Comment: Have you added jQuery.noConflict(); to your code?

Comment: will you please share your site link.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot, it is not yet live so it is locked.

Comment: https://github.com/digitalthink/Lightbox-JS. Just Google for 'lightbox Javascript -jQuery' and you might find something.

Comment: http://jslightbox.felixhagspiel.de/ is a small and plain JS lightbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Shutter Reloaded**

Not very animated but very nice lightbox.
I made some changes to the bottom buttons but I love the real full-screen feature.
More importantly it's small compact and no `jQuery` required.

http://www.laptoptips.ca/javascripts/shutter-reloaded/

Comment: no jquery needed, responsive and small: http://jslightbox.felixhagspiel.de/